# Match a string to a word in list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of suffixes and I want to check if my word ends with any of those and if it does I want to print it, I am doing the following:

```
if(string.endswith(any(word in my_list))):
        print string
        print" "
        print word
```

my_list is the list of suffixes. When I run it, it gives me error saying name 'word' is not defined

Answer (score 7):

`any` returns a boolean value.  `str.endswith` expects either a string or a `tuple` of strings.

You probably want something like:

```
if s.endswith(tuple(my_list)):
   print string
```

or if you actually want to know which one it matched:

```
suffix = next((word for word in my_list if s.endswith(word)),False)
if suffix:
    print word, suffix
```